# Каков синтаксис для функционального аналога SELECT TOP(N) в Oracle?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, oracle, plsql-developer

Предположим, есть таблица TABLE

```
ID | DEF
 1 | Один
 2 | Два
 3 | Три
 4 | Четыре
```

Тогда запрос в MS SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP(2) * FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Даст нам выдачу:

```
ID | DEF
 4 | Четыре
 3 | Три
```

А аналогичный запрос в Oracle (аналог, который мне предложился в интернетах)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROWNUM <= 2 ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Даст нам выдачу:

```
ID | DEF
 2 | Два
 1 | Один
```

Как получить действительно аналогичный по функциональности синтаксис для Oracle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В оракле до 11-й версии включительно - через подзапрос с `row_number`:

```
select *
  from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id desc) rn
          from t)
 where rn <= 2
```

В 12-й версии появился синтаксис для первых N строк с `LIMIT` и `OFFSET`, почти как в постгресе (запрос скопипастил из интернета, 12-го оракла под рукой нет):

```
 select *
   from t
  order by id desc
 OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 7):

Дело в том, что `Oracle` сначала выполняет условие `where` и только потом производит сортировку. То есть в вашем случае сначала остаются строки с `id in (1, 2)` и потом они и сортируются.

Для получения аналогичного результата сначала надо отсортировать все данные и потом обернув запрос получить нужное количество строк:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM   TABLE 
      ORDER  BY ID DESC) 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам придётся воспользоваться подзапросом. Т.е. ваш запрос с основными условиями и сортировкой перенесите в подзапрос, а ограничение на выбор поставьте в секцию `WHERE` внешнего запроса.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (
  SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
  ORDER BY ID DESC 
  )
WHERE 
ROWNUM <= 2
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибся. Завтра поправлю.

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с версии [12.1.0.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHFGAA) *Oracle* БД поддерживает введённый в стандарте [SQL:2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause) `FETCH FIRST|NEXT` синтаксис [(см. *row_limiting_clause* для полного описания)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6).

Воспроизводимый рабочий пример:

```sql
with tab (id, def) as (
    select rownum, trim (column_value)
    from xmlTable ('"Один", "Два", "Три", "Четыре"')
) 
select *
from tab
order by id desc
fetch first 2 rows only;
```

Результат:

```
        ID DEF       
---------- ----------
         4 Четыре    
         3 Три
```

Надо отметить, что поддерживаемый *MS SQL Server* `SELECT TOP(N)` синтаксис не является стандартным.