# Группировка с зависимой максимизацией двух столбцов (без подзапросов)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть задача вывести все строки, группируя таблицу по столбцу `t_name`, при этом максимизируя по двум столбцам `t_date` и `t_num`, так что

1. вначале максимизируя по столбцу `t_num`
2. затем оставшаяся выборка максимизируется по `t_date`

**Вопрос: можно ли это организовать без подзапросов (например, оконными функциями или другими способами), и будет ли это работать быстрее?**

Для примера

```
   t_name   t_date      t_num
1  aaa      20.01.2018  3
2  aaa      03.01.2018  10
3  aaa      01.01.2018  10
4  aaa      (null)      10
5  bbb      19.01.2018  1
6  bbb      (null)      10
```

1. в результате максимизации по столбцу `t_num` останутся значения

```
   t_name   t_date      t_num
2  aaa      03.01.2018  10
3  aaa      01.01.2018  10
4  aaa      (null)      10
6  bbb      (null)      10
```

2. затем выборку максимизируется по столбцу `t_date` и останутся значения

```
   t_name   t_date      t_num
2  aaa      03.01.2018  10
6  bbb      (null)      10
```

Это легко можно сделать через подзапросы

```
SELECT
  T.T_NAME,
  MAX(T.T_DATE) AS T_DATE,
  G.T_NUM 
FROM 
  TEST_GROUPING T
  INNER JOIN (
               SELECT T_NAME, MAX(T_NUM) AS T_NUM 
               FROM TEST_GROUPING 
               GROUP BY T_NAME
             ) G ON G.T_NAME = T.T_NAME AND G.T_NUM = T.T_NUM
GROUP BY
  T.T_NAME,
  G.T_NUM
```

Comment: *можно ли это организовать без подзапросов (например, оконными функциями или другими способами), и будет ли это работать быстрее?* 1) Легко. Т.н. "Бабушкин метод". 2) Нет (будет однопроходный фуллскан).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, оконными функциями делается элементарно:

```
with t (t_name, t_date, t_num) as (
      select 'aaa', to_date('20.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 3 from dual union all
      select 'aaa', to_date('03.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 10 from dual union all
      select 'aaa', to_date('01.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 10 from dual union all
      select 'aaa', null, 10 from dual union all
      select 'bbb', to_date('20.01.2018', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 1 from dual union all
      select 'bbb', null, 10 from dual)
select t_name, t_date, t_num
  from (select t_name, t_date, t_num,
               row_number() over (partition by t_name order by t_num desc, t_date desc nulls last) rn
          from t)
 where rn = 1
```

Работать тоже должно быстро, особенно если у вас есть индекс по `t_num`, а лучше даже по `(t_num, t_date)`.

Comment: Дмитрий, решение с оконной функцией выдает результат
1) ааа,(null),10  2) bbb,(null),10. Это можно попаравить, например добавив case по дате в оконную функцию

Comment: @ДаниилРоманов Я просто не тестировал на реальных данных. Попробуйте заменить `t_date desc` на `t_date desc nulls last`. Должно помочь. Если не поможет, тогда посмотрю повнимательнее, где накосячил.

Comment: Дмитрий, второе решение выдает только одно значение по `t_name`  `1) bbb, 20.01.2018, 10`. К сожалению, у `bbb` нет такой даты

Comment: Да просто лень брать ваши данные, создавать под них таблицу, заполнять, писать все эти бесконечные `to_date(...)`. Вот если б вы скрипт сами заготовили, цены б вам не было. Ну ладно, уговорили, сейчас сделаю.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE TEST_GROUPING 
(
  T_NAME VARCHAR2(10),
  T_DATE DATE,
  T_NUM NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPING VALUES ('aaa', TO_DATE('20.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), 3);
INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPING VALUES ('aaa', TO_DATE('03.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), 10);
INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPING VALUES ('aaa', TO_DATE('01.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), 10);
INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPING VALUES ('aaa', NULL, 10);
INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPING VALUES ('bbb', TO_DATE('19.01.2018','dd.mm.yyyy'), 1);
INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPING VALUES ('bbb', NULL, 10);`

Comment: Первое поправил,  со вторым решением немного мимо. Оно немного для других задач применяется, я его убрал вообще.

Comment: Дмитрий, благодарю за ваш отклик и развернутый ответ. Но вопрос остался открытым: **возможно ли это сделать без подзапроса?**

Comment: Сейчас попробую еще раз второй подход с `keep`. Как-то наверно можно выкрутиться. В 12-м оракле это должно быть проще, см. [мой ответ тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751644/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0-select-topn-%D0%B2-oracle/751660#751660)

Comment: @ДаниилРоманов а чем вам не угодил подзапрос?

Comment: @ДаниилРоманов А если `WITH t (t_name, t_date, t_num) AS (..исх.данные..), tt (t_name, t_date, t_num, rn) AS (select t_name, t_date, t_num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t_name ORDER BY t_num DESC, t_date DESC NULLS LAST) rn FROM t) SELECT t_name, t_date, t_num FROM tt WHERE rn=1`- это для Вас будет "без подзапроса"?

Comment: @Viktorov всегда думал, что с ними запрос выполняется дольше, я эту задачу потом масштабирую для огромной таблицы из млрд строк

Comment: @ДаниилРоманов Думаю, вам это пригодится в качестве пищи для размышления: http://www.xt-r.com/2012/09/distinct-values-topn.html Показано, как для подобной задачи выжать все соки из оракла. Как раз ваш случай.

Comment: @ДаниилРоманов Наличие подзапроса само по себе не говорит о том, быстро будет выполнятся запрос или нет. Оптимизатор сам принимает решения относительно того как именно выполнять запрос. И он вполне может развернуть 10 уровней вложенных подзапросов в одну простую операцию, если увидит для этого возможность. В любом случае надо смотреть план выполнения (explain plan) имеющегося запроса и при наличии проблем пробовать его переформулировать.