# Доступ к последнему полученному пакету

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Есть оборудование, которое каждую 1-2 секунды (если все нормально) шлет пакет из 4 полей. Этот пакет сохраняется в лог-таблицу базы (каждый пакет - отдельная запись). Кроме того, нужно для клиента обеспечить отображение данных последнего пакета.

Как это лучше сделать? Запросом

```
SELECT * FROM packets WHERE device_id = :id HAVING id = MAX(id)
```

или ведением таблицы `last_packets` и регулярным обновлением этой таблицы? (лог таблица нужна в любом случае)

СУБД Оракл. Количество таких устройств до 200.

И еще момент - если в момент получения пакета клиент подключен к серверу, то этому клиенту пакет отдается напрямую. Т.е. клиенту нет необходимости постоянно обращаться в базу. Доступ к последнему пакету нужен когда оборудование перестало передавать данные, а в момент передачи клиент отсутствовал

Comment: Типичная задача "получить топ-N записей" (в вашем случае N=1). См., например, тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751644/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-select-topn-%d0%b2-oracle

Comment: @Dmitry т.е. Вы считаете, что вывести запись с последним id будет правильнее всего? Повторюсь записей **очень** много. Подзапрос не выберет их все, пока не увидит во внешнем запросе условие `WHERE ROWNUM = 1`?

Comment: Если у вас `id` гарантированно возрастает, то почему бы и нет? И потом, сортировать необязательно по `id`, по дате тоже можно. Если индекс есть, он тоже должен использоваться, тогда и скорость почти не будет зависеть от размера таблицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас, получается, пишется в таблицу 200 записей в секунду. При таком потоке, имхо, держать отдельную постоянно обновляемую таблицу бессмысленно. Оракл справится, конечно, но зачем? Но и всю историю держать тоже неудобно, потому что таблица растет, а большинство запросов запрашивают только последнюю запись. Я бы так сделал: отдельную историческую таблицу, в которую джобом раз в час, например, скидывать из основной таблицы все, что старше трех часов, а в основной таблице скопированный кусок удалять. Оставшийся кусок будет маленьким (`200 * 3600 * 3 = 2 160 000` строк), запросы будут быстро отрабатывать.
Ну и составной индекс по полям `(device_id, log_time)`. Дальше запрос, выбирающий последнюю запись по каждому девайсу, как описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751644/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0-select-topn-%d0%b2-oracle/751660#751660), или можно еще как вариант одним запросом взять все устройства и для каждого получить последнюю запись:

```
select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by log_date) last_dev_id,
       device_id, max(log_date) over (aprtition by device_id)
  from packets
 group by device_id
```

Comment: Спасибо. Идея ясна. 200 записей в секунду это пик. В среднем будет порядка 100. Конечно слегка усложнится выборка по архиву, но она будет нечасто выполняться